# Why does return false still allow the submission of the form?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to populate a form field prior to it being submitted however the function appears to be disregarded and am unsure whether I am doing it incorrectly. Why is the form allowed to be submitted even though I am returning false?

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />
    <meta name="robot" content="noindex, nofollow" />

    <title> sample form</title>

    <base href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="" />

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function formDetails() {
        var name = document.forms["sampleform"]["name"].value = "test"
        return false;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="sampleform" name="sampleform" action="" method="get">
    <p><label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="50" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="formDetails();" /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the return value on to the event handler itself:

```
<input ... onClick="return formDetails();" ... />
```

Comment: Also wouldn't this be better as an onSubmit on the form element itself?

Comment: @JonTaylor Probably, but not necessarily. For instance, the form may contain more than one submit button that should do different validations when clicked. Not that that's something I'd do, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Yeah very true, I tend to test which submit in an onSubmit function rather than having seperate functions.

Comment: @Kolink - Do you mean `onClick="formDetails();return false;"`? If so why does it have to return the value to the event handler itself? What purpose does the `return false` within the function serve then?

Comment: No, I mean `return formDetails()`. That way, whatever `formDetails` returns is passed back to the handler. So if `formDetails` returns `false`, the action is cancelled.

Comment: @Kolink - But I am already doing that and the form still submits.

Comment: Not according to your question, you're not. Your question just has `onClick="formDetails();"`, I'm telling you to use `onClick="return formDetails();"`.

Comment: @Kolink - Sorry. I missed that completely. I didn't notice the `return` prior to the function name. Sorry for being such a n00b but why do I have use `return` as opposed to calling the function directly?

Comment: Calling the function gets the return value, but you still have to pass it back as the return value of the event handler.

Comment: @Kolink - Sorry if I don't follow as quickly. If the function returns the value `false`, why do I have to pass it back to the event handler?

Comment: Because how else is the event handler supposed to know whether to continue the default event or not?

Comment: @Kolink - So if it has a return value of `false` does this not affect the default behaviour?